# Error messages don't go away in angular forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ngrx

I have an issue is that the error messages doesn't appear in form fields.

In ngOnInit() I declare this code for removing the error message, this code call removeTooltips() just by hovering over the fields , and by removing this I can see error messages appear but the problem they do not go away. :

```
this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(() => {
      this.removeTooltips();
    });
```

and :

```
removeTooltips(): void {
    console.log("removeTooltips");
    this.firstName= [];`
  }
```

HTML :

```
<!-- First name -->
      <section class='form-group first-name' *ngIf='mode !== userFormUpdateMode.UPDATE_MULTIPLE'>
        <label for='user-first-name'>{{'user.form.label.firstName' | translate}} :</label>
        <input type='text' id='user-first-name' formControlName='firstName' placeholder='Nicolas' cxmSmartflowCxmTooltip
               [value]='titleCase(this.formGroup.get("firstName")?.value || "")'
               [tooltipText]='firstNameErrorMessage | translate'
               [showTooltip]='errorFormControl.includes(userFormProperties.FIRST_NAME)'>
      </section>
```

Comment: inside removeTooltips try to add ``` this.formGroup.get('firstName').setErrors(null);```

Comment: @MoufeedJuboqji is still the same problem, errors message does'nt appear 
ps : I added  this.formGroup.get('firstName')?.setErrors(null);

Comment: Sorry did you try to print firstName errors ?  also what is inside the errorFormControl  
```
<div *ngIf='formGroup.get("firstName")?.invalid' class='error-message'>
    {{firstNameErrorMessage | translate}}
  </div> 
```

Comment: errorFormControl   is a list of message fields in form